# Issues moving a page into VisualForce

Tags: visualforce, javascript, css, html

have a page that was coded outside of force.com and I have to move it into a Visualforce page.

Then, just for kicks, I took the source of the page out of force.com (where it doesn't work) and created a new html page on my desktop. It works again... because these two lines are not loading:

```
<script src="/faces/a4j/g/3_3_3.Finalorg.ajax4jsf.javascript.AjaxScript?rel=1395179288000" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/static/111213/js/perf/stub.js"></script></head><body><span id="j_id0:Scrolling"><span id="j_id0:Scrolling.start" style="display: none"></span><script type="text/javascript">
window.document.getElementById('j_id0:Scrolling.start').onstart=function(){startScrolling();;};
</script>
```

They appear to be causing a conflict - but I don't understand enough to be able to say what it is.

VFPage

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" showChat="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" cache="false" docType="html-5.0" >
    <apex:actionStatus onstart="startScrolling();" id="Scrolling"/>
    <head>
        <title>Learning Portal</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.PartnerLearningPortal,'PartnerLearningPortal/css/demo.css')}" />
        <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.PartnerLearningPortal,'PartnerLearningPortal/css/style.css')}" />
        <apex:stylesheet value="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Playfair+Display:400italic)" />
        <!-- <noscript>
            <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.PartnerLearningPortal,'PartnerLearningPortal/css/noscript.css')}"/>
        </noscript>-->

        <!--apex:includeScript value="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js" /-->
        <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.PartnerLearningPortal,'PartnerLearningPortal/js/jquery.min.js')}"/>
        <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.PartnerLearningPortal,'PartnerLearningPortal/js/jquery.eislideshow.js')}"/>
        <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.PartnerLearningPortal,'PartnerLearningPortal/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js')}"/>
        <apex:includeScript loadOnReady="True" value="
            $(function() {
                $('#ei-slider').eislideshow({
                    animation           : 'left',
                    autoplay            : true,
                    slideshow_interval  : 9000,
                    titlesFactor        : 0
                });
            });"/>
   </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
              <h2><span class="right">
                <a href="" target="_self">contact support@xxxx.com</a></span>
              </h2>
              <div class="clr"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="headerdpic">
            <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.PartnerLearningPortal, 'PartnerLearningPortal/images/PartnerPortal_Homepage_Header.png')}" width="100%" height="auto"/>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div  class="ei-slider">
                    <ul class="ei-slider-large">
                        <li>
                            <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.PartnerLearningPortal, 'PartnerLearningPortal/images/large/6.jpg')}" alt="image06"/>
                            <div class="ei-title">
                                <h2>Passionate</h2>
                                <h3>Seeker</h3>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.PartnerLearningPortal, 'PartnerLearningPortal/images/large/1.jpg')}" alt="image01" />
                            <div class="ei-title">
                                <h2>Creative</h2>
                                <h3>Duet</h3>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.PartnerLearningPortal, 'PartnerLearningPortal/images/large/2.jpg')}" alt="image02" />
                            <div class="ei-title">
                                <h2>Friendly</h2>
                                <h3>Devil</h3>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.PartnerLearningPortal, 'PartnerLearningPortal/images/large/3.jpg')}" alt="image03"/>
                            <div class="ei-title">
                                <h2>Tranquilent</h2>
                                <h3>Compatriot</h3>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.PartnerLearningPortal, 'PartnerLearningPortal/images/large/4.jpg')}" alt="image04"/>
                            <div class="ei-title">
                                <h2>Insecure</h2>
                                <h3>Hussler</h3>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.PartnerLearningPortal, 'PartnerLearningPortal/images/large/5.jpg')}" alt="image05"/>
                            <div class="ei-title">
                                <h2>Loving</h2>
                                <h3>Rebel</h3>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.PartnerLearningPortal, 'PartnerLearningPortal/images/large/7.jpg')}" alt="image07"/>
                            <div class="ei-title">
                                <h2>Crazy</h2>
                                <h3>Friend</h3>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul> <!-- ei-slider-large -->
                    <ul class="ei-slider-thumbs" >
                        <li class="ei-slider-element">Current</li>
                        <li><a href="#"></a><apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.PartnerLearningPortal, 'PartnerLearningPortal/images/thumbs/6.jpg')}" alt="thumb06" /></li>
                        <li><a href="#"></a><apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.PartnerLearningPortal, 'PartnerLearningPortal/images/thumbs/1.jpg')}" alt="thumb01" /></li>
                        <li><a href="#"></a><apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.PartnerLearningPortal, 'PartnerLearningPortal/images/thumbs/2.jpg')}" alt="thumb02" /></li>
                        <li><a href="#"></a><apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.PartnerLearningPortal, 'PartnerLearningPortal/images/thumbs/3.jpg')}" alt="thumb03" /></li>
                        <li><a href="#"></a><apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.PartnerLearningPortal, 'PartnerLearningPortal/images/thumbs/4.jpg')}" alt="thumb04" /></li>
                        <li><a href="#"></a><apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.PartnerLearningPortal, 'PartnerLearningPortal/images/thumbs/5.jpg')}" alt="thumb05" /></li>
                        <li><a href="#"></a><apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.PartnerLearningPortal, 'PartnerLearningPortal/images/thumbs/7.jpg')}" alt="thumb07" /></li>
                    </ul><!-- ei-slider-thumbs -->
                </div><!-- ei-slider -->
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                <div style="float:left;">
                    <div style="float:left; width:55%;"><apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.PartnerLearningPortal, 'PartnerLearningPortal/images/PartnerPortal_Homepage_ProdEd.png')}" width="100%" height="auto"/>
                    </div>
                    <div style="float:left; width:35%; padding-left:20px;">
                    <h3><b>Online Learning</b></h3><p>Learn just-in-time and at your own pace.  Beginner to advanced topics are available and accompanied by supporting resources, enabling you 
                    to continuously learn and progress to advanced concepts and techniques.</p><br/>
                    <h3><b>Instructor-Led</b></h3><p>Expect a highly interactive, hands-on experience in our classes, and a focus on practical knowledge and skills transfer. 
                    <a href="http://www.com/en/resources/events-webinars/" target="_blank">View Events</a> to attend an upcoming class at a location or browse our Catalog for our 
                    full list of offerings.</p><br/>
                    <h3><b>Communities</b></h3><p><a href="http://www.com/en/communities/" target="_blank">Visit Communities</a> to find the experts and information you need to 
                    collaborate, support your business, and solve common challenges.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            </div><!-- wrapper -->
        </div>
    </body>

</apex:page>
```

***EDIT***

So I changed those two lines to point to the actual files, one at a time to see which causes the error but neither does - which is confusing.

```
<script src="https://cs30.visual.force.com/faces/a4j/g/3_3_3.Finalorg.ajax4jsf.javascript.AjaxScript?rel=1395179288000" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="https://cs30.visual.force.com/static/111213/js/perf/stub.js"></script></head><body><span id="j_id0:Scrolling"><span id="j_id0:Scrolling.start" style="display: none"></span><script type="text/javascript">
```

window.document.getElementById('j_id0:Scrolling.start').onstart=function(){startScrolling();;};

Comment: can you show the markup of your visualforce page?

Comment: where are the a4j source files located? If they are on your pc, SF will not be able to load them since it cannot access your local PC. You will have to put them in SF as a Static Resource.

Comment: added markup. The items are all in a Static Resource - but the a4j is not mine and is an addition made by Salesforce platform

Comment: Have you tried using `jQuery.no conflict()`?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are specifying the body try changing this line to:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" showChat="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" cache="false" docType="html-5.0 applyHtmlTag="false">
```

Comment: That didn't work - thank you though